# Google Drive Realtime API "get" endpoint not working as expected

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

We are trying to use the Google Drive API to retrieve the model of a Realtime document ([API reference](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/realtime/get)). However, if I call the "get" method to retrieve details of a Realtime File generated through the [Google Drive Realtime API Playground](https://realtimeplayground.appspot.com/) app (with a blank "revision" field), the result is always:

```
{
  "appId": "292824132082",
  "revision": 1, 
  "data": null
}
```

even after a lot of editing on the model. If I try to specify a different revision (say, "2") the result is a 500 error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": 500,
  "message": null
 }
}
```

Are we doing something wrong or is there a problem with this specific API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling "get" using the API Playground gets the realtime document associated with the API playground app, not the realtime document associated with your app.

If you update and get both with the API playground you should see contents.